# Having CountDownTimer to restart when it finishes

Tags: android

How can i have the timer to restart when it finishes and displays a TextView

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `this.start()` in the onFinshed() method.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to just call `start()` in the `onFinish` method. But, you may prefer to use the Timer class instead: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also schedule a `TimerTask` for repeated execution:

```
myTimer.schedule(myTimerTask, 30000, 30000);
```

If you want to stop it, you can implement a true/false check in the task's `run()` method.