# Countdown timer doesn't start with new value set for time

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I use time countdown timer in 00:00 format with this code:

```
int timeCount = 150000;

public String formatTime(long millis) {  
                    String output = "00:00";  
                    long seconds = millis / 1000;  
                    long minutes = seconds / 60;  

                    seconds = seconds % 60;  
                    minutes = minutes % 60;  

                    String sec = String.valueOf(seconds);  
                    String min = String.valueOf(minutes);  

                    if (seconds < 10)  
                        sec = "0" + seconds;  
                    if (minutes < 10)  
                        min= "0" + minutes;  

                    output = min + " : " + sec;  
                    return output;
                }


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.kviz);

brojacVremena.start();
}

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
         public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
             super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
         }

         public void onFinish() {


         }
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             vreme.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }
         }
   MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(timeCount, 1000) 
   {

       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
       {
           vreme.setText("" + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
       }

       public void onFinish() 
       {
        finish();
       }
   };
```

And that works fine. But, when my game ends I start a popup with startActivityForResult and after user press OK button in it, I start next level and I need to update my time. It's not 150000ms anymore,it's something different now. I do it like this:

```
static final int MY_REQUEST2 = 1;

Intent i = new Intent(Kviz.this, Popup_nivoi.class);
                numberOfQuestions = 13;
                timeCount = 160000;
                i.putExtra("time", 160);
startActivityForResult(i, MY_REQUEST2);
```

Here I update int variable timeCount with new value, but when the timer starts, i goes from 150 seconds again.
What am I doing wrong?

This method works fine with few other variables I use in this class, for point, errors, tries left etc. Only time variable does not update.

Comment: dont you just want `i.putExtra("time",timeCount)`? or am I misunderstanding this completely

Comment: That thing is just to show the user in that popup how much time he has, using TextView. I did not need to put that here in code.

Comment: The line where I reset time variable is timeCount = 160000;. But the problem is that when I start countdown again it starts from the "old" time.

Comment: Oh okay, maybe then its because your `timeCount` was already passed into the `CountDown` timer, you need to reset the `millisUntilFinished` or `millisInFuture`

Comment: Well I thought that the CountDown timer will check that variable every time it starts. How to do that reset you mentioned?

Comment: Well it seems that you are passing that value into the `CountDown` timer and I am assuming that it is making a local copy of it and putting it into either `millisUntilFinished` or `millisInFuture`.  You would have to either make or use an existing method call that allows you to reset those values

Comment: I tried to find how to do that, but nothing. Can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: I dont know how you have the code designed when you restart the timer in your next level... maybe look at some of these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221829/restart-countdown-timer-with-new-time-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537748/having-countdowntimer-to-restart-when-it-finishes

Comment: @marjanbaz were you able to get the countdown timer to accept new time values? I am stuck right now.